# how to pre-configure opensearch with a dashboard

Tags: dashboard, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I'm trying to make a pre-config for opensearch-dashboard container, so if you pull it on different env it would containt already made dahsboards, discovers etc.

I'm able to create a dashboards, but in opensearch-dashboards.yaml I can't see a path to where to upload jsons with created dashboard.

That's quite silly but I would very much appreciate if someone helped me.

I checked /var/lib/opensearch-dashboards, /usr/share/opensearch-dashboards,/etc/opensearch-dashboards - I don't see any mentions of where to store my pre-configured dashboards, indicies and discovers.
When I created a dashboard in UI I couldn't find it stored within the container.

In UI I see saved objects button, it suggests to export or import objects, but i don't wanna do it with UI.